# C++ test whether matrix has been initialized

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, matrix, initialization

I have a `double** mat`, and I want to test whether it has already been initialized. If not, I allocate memory space for it. Is this working? :

```
if(!mat)
{
      mat = new double*[dim1];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < dim1 ; i++)
          mat[i] = new double[dim2];
}
```

What am I testing with `if(! mat)` ?

thanks

Comment: As a side note, I hope you are completely sure you actually need an array of arrays (which for a matrix is never appropriate) and you don't just sacrifice proper memory layout because you want to use the convenient `[i][j]` syntax directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what that you are checking in:

```
if (!mat)
```

is if the location `mat` is pointing to is `NULL` (0).

this well work just if the default for pointers is zero, of if you have declared your pointer like this:

```
double ** mat = NULL;
```

Comment: so I am better with `if(mat == NULL)` to test whether mat has not been initialized (?)

Comment: if you didnt initialize you will fail with this check but you will find only rubbish on pointers's address

Comment: @fonjibe, the point is that it only works if you initialize your `mat` variable with `double ** mat = NULL`, which is a good style anyway (use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` if you have C++11). If you define it just as `double ** mat` (without initializing), this will not work

Comment: @fonjibe No, both are exactly the same. `!mat` translates to `mat == NULL`. What he meant to say is you have to make sure mat initially has the value NULL.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall ...unless `mat` is a `static` pointer variable, those are initialized to `NULL` implicitly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!mat)
```

is pretty much a shorthand for

```
if (mat==nullptr)
```

(nullptr being the C++11 keyword; you can use the NULL macro or just the literal 0 as well).

Of course, this only makes sense if "mat" is actually initialized with a nullptr, for example because it's a global/static variable (jhappens automatically for these), or you did initialize it with the nullptr.

Personally, I don't like constructs like "!mat". I always make the nullptr comparision explicit, since we're talking pointers here, not booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Before check you must initialize `mat` pointer with NULL (0) or nullptr(for c++11) value. `if (!mat)` checks pointer value with true or false. NULL or nullptr always as false value and other is true values. Its like `if (mat == NULL)` or `if (mat == nullptr)`

Comment: isn't `if(!mat)` rather to be replaced by `if(mat == NULL)` ?